# How to convert json data into an array in C#.?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

```
{
"shapes":[{"id":"A","cursor":"pointer","visual":null,"x":69.25,"y":50},{"name":"Right"},{"name":"Auto"}],"width":10,"height":10},"undoable":true},
{"id":"B","cursor":"pointer","visual":null,"x":69.25,"y":50},{"name":"Right"},{"name":"Auto"}],"width":10,"height":10},"undoable":true}],
"connections":[{"id":"8Op6PApGWW","selectable":true,"serializable":true,"from":{"shapeId":"A"},"toX":null,"toY":null,"to":{"shapeId":"B"}}]
},
```

This is my json data, Now i have to deserialize it and fetch the Id of shapes and from and to id's connections.

I have tried like this.

```
string jsonString = Diagram.ResponseData.diagram;
JObject jsondata = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

But i am getting somethig First, Last, Child these properties.

i want like jsondata[0]shapes and in second index connections so i can access the properties of those...

Comment: You've got invalid JSON. Paste into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and see

Comment: @abatishchev its showing a valid msg after parsing my json.

Comment: I'm seeing this when copy&pasted the JSON from your question: https://imgur.com/hP8vKWV

Answer (score 1):

The JSON example you have posted is not valid JSON.   Assuming this is a Typo then...

You are currently creating a JObject from your JSON.  If you want an array then you need to deserialise as an object which contains an array (judging by your data example).

First you will need to create classes which matches your JSON input.  You can do this by pasting your (valid) JSON into visual studio as Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes (create new class first).

This should create a Root object with your inner data inside.  You can then deserialise  like this

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
var shapeArray = root.Shapes;
```

Comment: I cannot create classes for those, I am pasting my jsonstring data into a https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and its showing its a valid message.

Comment: @TauFeeQ  If I copy & past the JSON from your question then it reports and invalid.  So then you have pasted it incorrect into the question, so please update it.

Comment: @json.kaisersmith actual data i cannot paste here as its exceeding by 6000 characters. if u are pasting into the same url i mentioned in previouse comment then plz tell me which option do i need to select from dropdown

Comment: Create a new Class.  Go into that class, then select Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes